# match case in micropython - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, micropython, python-3.10, raspberry-pi-pico

I am using python 3.10.5 on my raspberry pi pico and I am trying to use `match` & `case` instead of `if` statements When I try to run the program it returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 22
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here is my function:

```
async def BlueTooth(delay):
    while True:
        if uart.any():
            command = uart.readline()
            #print(command)   # uncomment this line to see the received data
            match command:
                case b'1':
                    led.value(1)
                case b'0':
                    led.value(0)
            write_i2c("cmd: {}\n{}".format(command, Commands.get_command_action(str(command))))

        await asyncio.sleep(delay)
```

I have checked, and everything should be normal, what can cause the problem?
BTW, I am using `Thonny` as my editor.

Comment: The line beginning with `write_i2c` needs to be indented to put it inside the second `case`, or dedented to take it out of `match`.

Comment: still gives error

Comment: Which line is line 22?

Comment: "`match command:`"

Comment: Why is this tagged `python-3.10` if you're not using that version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [micropython's README.md](https://github.com/micropython/micropython):

> MicroPython implements the entire Python 3.4 syntax (including exceptions, `with`, `yield from`, etc., and additionally `async`/`await` keywords from Python 3.5 and some select features from later versions).

`match`/`case` are new as of Python 3.10, six releases after the last version of the Python language spec MicroPython claims full support for. And it's a ridiculously complex addition to the language (relying on a complete replacement of the simpler LL(1) parser with a more flexible/powerful/complex PEG parser among other things). They don't support it yet, [but it's on their todo list](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/7847). When it's supported, [the "MicroPython differences from CPython » Python 3.10" docs](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/differences/python_310.html) should be updated to indicate that support is completed.

Comment: That's kinda confusing due to the fact when I checked the version it said it is 3.10.5/6 :\

Comment: @David: Ah, yes. Looking deeper, it looks like they do pick up bits and pieces from the latest releases; your version presumably is saying "this has all the stuff we cared to implement up through 3.10.5/6". Looks like their [differences from 3.10 docs](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/differences/python_310.html) have a note on the structural pattern matching that points to [this issue](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/7847) which summarizes to "We know it's part of Python now, but it's *really* hard to do" (for the same reasons I mentioned in the answer).

Comment: "And it's a ridiculously complex addition to the language" to really add very, very little value past "if/elif", truth be said.

Comment: @jsbueno: Well, for the OP's case anyway. There are some benefits for the more complicated pattern-matching and capture extractions, but yes, it doesn't (and due to Python's lack of static typing, mostly can't) actually optimize anything over `if/elif/else`, and the fact that it's a statement, not an expression, removes a number of use cases that Rust's match expression enables (Rust having `match` early on also means it's got greater support from built-in types). I wouldn't blame the MicroPython folks if they dragged their feet on this, or just documented it as an incompatibility.

Comment: I just saw the "break" in the O.P.'s match/case - would not that be a syntax error in regular Python? (yes, it would, but I had to check)